# Terraform, how to pass data from one child module to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following folder structure

```
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── web-app
│   │   ├── lambda.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── s3.tf
│   │   ├── sns.tf
│   │   ├── sqs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── microservice1
│   │   ├── sns.tf
│   │   ├── sqs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
...
```

Inside the `web-app` I create a SNS topic. Inside the `microservice` I want to subscribe the queue I create there to the topic I created inside the `web-app`.
My problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass the `arn of the topic` from web-app to the microservice1.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from `microservice1`. You have to do it in your `main.tf`. So first you instantiate a `web-app` module in the `main.tf`. The module outputs sns arn. Then you pass the arn to the instant of `microservice` module, again in `main.tf`

In `main.tf`:

```
module "web-app" {
   source = "./modules/web-app"
   # other arguments
}

module "microservice1" {
   source = "./modules/microservice1"
   sns_arn = module.web-app.sns_arn
   # other arguments
}
```

for that to work, you have to have output in your `web-app`:

```
output "sns_arn" {
  value = aws_sns_topic.mytopic.id
}
```

`/microservice1/variables.tf`

```
variable "sns_arn" {
  description="topic arn from web_app"
}
```